# How to do a complex join with sums/counts between multiple tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to write a complex (for me at least) query that joins a few tables to return data from a 'shifts' (think cashier shift at a store) table and sums of transactions that occurred during those shifts at a specific store.

I have a shifts table with the following info

- shiftID
- cashierID
- startTime
- endTime

A transactions table with this info

- transactionID
- branchID
- amount
- shiftID

A cashiers table with this info

- cashierID
- merchantID
- cashierName

A branches table with this info

- branchID
- merchantID

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT shifts.shiftID, 
       shifts.cashierID, 
       shifts.startTime, 
       cashiers.name as 'cashierName', 
       (SELECT sum(general_transactions.amount) from 
            general_transactions INNER JOIN shifts on 
            shifts.shiftID=general_transactions.shiftID 
            left join cashiers on cashiers.cashierID = shifts.cashierID 
            where general_transactions.amount > 0 AND shifts.endTime IS NOT NULL 
            and cashiers.merchantID=16) as 'loadUps' 
       from shifts LEFT JOIN cashiers on cashiers.cashierID = 
       shifts.cashierID where endTime is NOT NULL AND cashiers.merchantID = 16
```

So basically this works to return all the shifts with the info I need but it sums ALL transactions at this merchant in each row, not just those specific to the shift returned in that row.

Is it possible to query in a way that I get the totals of each shift with each shift row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SUM in a statement (or any aggregate function for that matter, such as COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX...) but you don't use a GROUP BY clause, then the function will be applied to the whole result set. This is why you get the sum of all the transactions.

Now, the SUM is inside your inner query. If you add the GROUP BY in there, then you'll most likely get errors, because more than one value will be returned. So you'll have to re-structure the query, perhaps take the SUM out and put it in the outer query, along with a GROUP BY clause.

PS: If you create an SQL fiddle and populate some data, I would gladly try and do it for you.

Comment: I'm working on creating a fiddle but keep in mind that I'm using the inner query because I need to calculate only amounts > 0 for example to only get load ups (this is a bi-directional transaction system, users can load up and purchase stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with thanks to @memo above:

Removed the sum from the inner query to the outer query and applied a case to the sum to check for values above 0. Like this:

```
select shifts.shiftID, 
       shifts.cashierID, 
       shifts.startTime, 
       cashiers.name as 'cashierName', 
       sum(
           CASE WHEN general_transactions.amount>0 
           THEN general_transactions.amount 
           ELSE 0 
           END
       ) as 'loadUps' 
  from shifts 
  LEFT JOIN cashiers 
       on cashiers.cashierID = shifts.cashierID 
  LEFT JOIN general_transactions 
       on general_transactions.shiftID = shifts.shiftID 
  where endTime is NOT NULL 
  AND cashiers.merchantID = 16 
  GROUP by shifts.shiftID;
```